# Juntar dois arrays caso campo for igual em ambos

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho dois arrays:

**exam:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Avaliação - Procedimento em Serras",
        "description": "Uma pequena descrição sobre a avaliação."
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Avaliação de Recuperação - Procedimento em Serras",
        "description": "Uma pequena descrição sobre a avaliação."
    }
]
```

**exam_score:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "score": "0.00",
        "exam_id": 1
    }
]
```

Preciso chegar se o campo `exam_id` do array `exam_score` é igual a algum campo `id` do array `exam`. Caso for igual, adicionar o campo `score` no array **merged** (abaixo)

```
const merged = exams.map((e) => ({
  ...e,
  exam_score: { ...exam_score.some(({ exam_id }) => exam_id === e.id) },
}));
```

Porém, estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> "message": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor

Essa é a forma correta de efetuar essa operação? O que esta errado?

Comment: Voce está usando `some` por que? Não seria um `filter`? `some` retorna somente `true/false`.

Comment: Né.. Some retorna um valor booleano. Muito obrigado!

Comment: _adicionar o campo score no array merged_ usando `some` voce vai retornar somente um booleano, nao vai fazer o merge.

Comment: O código que está na pergunta **não** gera o erro "*Converting circular structure to JSON*" ([veja](https://ideone.com/ni3YgU)), então o problema está em outra parte do código que não foi mostrada. Favor [edit] a pergunta, colocando um [mcve] que reproduza o problema.

Comment: De qualquer forma, não está claro qual deveria ser o resultado. Vc diz que o score deve ser adicionado no array `merged`, então como ficaria? Seria isso https://ideone.com/5zgUrU ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `some` retorna um `boolean`. Como você deseja encontrar o valor, o mais indicado é usar a função `find`:

```js
const exams = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Avaliação - Procedimento em Serras",
        "description": "Uma pequena descrição sobre a avaliação."
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Avaliação de Recuperação - Procedimento em Serras",
        "description": "Uma pequena descrição sobre a avaliação."
    }
];

const examScore = [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "score": "10.00",
        "exam_id": 1
    }
];

const defaultScore = { score: "0.00" };

const merged = exams.map((exam) => ({
  ...exam,
  score: (examScore.find(({ id }) => exam.id === id) ?? defaultScore).score
}));

console.log(merged);
```

---

> [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)
>
> O método `some()` testa se ao menos um dos elementos no `array` passa no teste implementado pela função atribuída e retorna um valor `true` ou `false`.

---

> [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
>
> O método `find()` retorna o valor do primeiro elemento do `array` que satisfizer a função de teste provida. Caso contrario, `undefined` é retornado.

Comment: O responsável pelo downvote pode explicar o que há de errado com a resposta?

Answer (score -1):

É um booleano, assim já resolveria:

```
exams.map(item => {
    const finded = exam_score.find(({ exam_id })=> exam_id === item.id)
    return {
        ...item,
        exam_score: finded && finded.score
    }
})
```

Comment: Tá errado, o `some` retorna um `boolean`. Ele precisa retornar o valor.

Comment: Se ele precisa do score já editei ai.